# Add number prefix to file names in a folder, based on the last prefix number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a folder with 10 files. I have been able to rename them all using a script I created to add '1 - ' at the beginning of the file names in order. So, each file starts with '1 - ', '2 - ' etc.

Two questions here:

1. When I re run the script, it does not recognise that the file already has a '1 - ' at the start and so it just adds another 'X - ' at the start of it again. E.g. '1 - 2 - XXXX'
2. I would like to add to the script to say, where the file already has a prefix of '1 - ' (1 can be any number), then the script should not rename it again (like point 1 above)
3. Finally, if I add any new files into the same folder, I would like the new files to have the prefix number from the last number in the folder e.g.

Folder contains:

1 - XXXX
2 - XXXX
3 - XXX

If I add a fourth file and run the script the new output should be:

1 - XXXX
2 - XXXX
3 - XXX
4 - XXX

Previous files are not affected and the new file starts at 4.

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
As requested, I have added my current script here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhVLl.png)

Comment: _using a script I created_ hmm. I think all you need is just to change a few lines in that script

Comment: Could you show your script? It's a fairly simple task actually.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich thanks for your response. It's not an 'ask and run' case, I got covid on Friday so haven't been able to function since. Please do not assume people's circumstances. I will review your comments once I am able to.

Comment: Well. I'm sorry if you got sick. It changes the matter. I've removed my comment. Get well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

```
function renum_files() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('###'); // paste your folder ID here
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var files_to_renum = [];          // array of files to renum
  var already_numered_files = [];   // array of file names that already have number

  // fill the two arrays with files or file names
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getName().match(/^\d+ -/)) {
      already_numered_files.push(file.getName())
    } else {
      files_to_renum.push(file);
    }
  }

  // do nothing if there are no files
  if (files_to_renum.length == 0) return;
  
  // sort the files alphabetically
  files_to_renum.sort((a,b) => 
    a.getName().toLowerCase() > b.getName().toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1);
  
  // set the counter
  var counter = 0;

  // UPDATE --------------

  if (already_numered_files.length > 0) {

    // get all numbers
    var counters = already_numered_files.map(x => x.split(' - ')[0]);

    // get a bigger number from the numbers
    counter = Math.max(...counters);
  }
  
  // END UPDATE ----------

  // rename the files
  files_to_renum.forEach(f => f.setName(++counter + ' - ' + f.getName()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. As requested I added a picture of my current script above, which is what I created to add '1 - ' at the beginning of each file name! My script is slightly different as its based on adding a link to the Google Sheet directly, but I think I can tweak that myself. I did try sooo many times to work out how to add a regex into the script but it just wouldn't work! This part ' if (file.getName().match(/^\d+ -/)) {' is exactly what I was missing! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad if it works. Hope you're well. Let me know if you need help with the code.

Comment: Thank you I am feeling much better this week. I have been able to use snippets of your code - thank you. Question: When the folder has 10 files it correctly numbers the files up until 10. But when I add the 11 + files, it says the 'last number' is 9 and therefore renames all new files with a '10 - ' at the start. I think its to do with the regex as we used 'd' which represents one digit but the folder could contain 100s of files, so it should look at the last highest numeric digit/digits and then start from the next one. I did 'dd' but then it renames all the files again @Yuri

Comment: I think it might be the 'slice(-1)' part of the script? If I run the flow with 20 files it numbers it correctly, but lets say I add another file into the folder and rerun, it sees the last largest number as 9 and not 20..

Comment: Oops. My bad. It turned out that the standard method `sort()` sorts the elements of an array as strings [1,10,2,3...9] (even if they are numbers), not as numbers [1,2,3,...9,10]. And since the code took the last element of the sorted array it got '9' instead of '10'. Now it takes a bigger number from the array `Math.max(...array)`. Try the updated code.

Comment: thank you that worked! Pleae could you explain what the three dots here do? counter = Math.max(...counters);

Comment: `...` is so-called "spread" operator. It turns an array into a sequence of values: [1,2,3] --> 1, 2, 3. The `Math.max()` takes a sequence of numbers as arguments.